# Hibernate Extra Lazy loading and Memory

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, lazy-loading

Ref to the **Extra** Lazy loading sample [**here**](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/hibernate-extra-lazy-collection-fetching).

Is there a way to free the memory occupied `wines.get(0)` before `wines.get(1)` is called in `extraLazyInitializationOfWines()` ?

Any help will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can evict single object from first level Hibernate cache. Example from [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html)

```
ScrollableResult cats = sess.createQuery("from Cat as cat").scroll(); //a huge result set
while ( cats.next() ) {
    Cat cat = (Cat) cats.get(0);
    doSomethingWithACat(cat);
    sess.evict(cat);
}
```